# Can't call slot or Q_INVOKABLE from QML in subclass of QQmlPropertyMap

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtcore

I'm trying to test drive the `QQmlPropertyMap` class. It seems like it might work well for what I want, if I can subclass it. The documentation [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qtqml/qqmlpropertymap.html) even gives some rudimentary instructions on what to do for subclassing it. Said documentation also indicates that this class derives from `QObject`.

For what it's worth, I'm using QtCreator 2.6.1 on Qt 5.0.0 with QtQuick 2.0.

My main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        text: owner.field
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            owner.testFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

My main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include "TestMap.h"
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TestMap* map = new TestMap();
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    QQmlContext* ctxt = viewer.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("owner", map);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/TestMap/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();
    return app.exec();
}
```

My TestMap.h

```
#ifndef TESTMAP_H
#define TESTMAP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlPropertyMap>
#include <QDebug>

class TestMap: public QQmlPropertyMap  // QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TestMap(QObject* parent = 0): QQmlPropertyMap(this, parent)  // QObject(parent)
    {
        insert("field", "value");   // Comment this out
    }
    TestMap(const TestMap& value) { }
    virtual ~TestMap() {}

public slots:
    void testFunc()
    {
        qDebug() << "Success!";
    }
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TestMap)
#endif
```

When I run, I get a window saying "value", as I'd expect. But when I click on the window, I get a console output saying

```
TypeError: Property 'testFunc' of object TestMap(0xaaa0b8) is not a function
```

I've looked for similar problems, but all the search results are about people that forgot to include the `Q_OBJECT` macro. It must be something I'm doing wrong in the code, because if I make all the changes indicated in the comments of the TestMap file (and leave the main.cpp and main.qml exactly as is), I get the `qDebug` message I expect.

I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` or not (I think the 2-arg protected constructor is supposed to do it for me), but it doesn't work either way.

For the record, the only things I have to change to get it to work are:

1) Derive from `QObject` instead of `QQmlPropertyMap`.

2) Change the constructor to:

```
TestMap(QObject* parent = 0): QObject(parent) {}
```

And that's it. Since it works when I don't change anything about the main.cpp, main.qml, or the slot itself, I have to conclude it's nothing wrong with those. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For anyone who is following this or who finds it later via Google, this is apparently a bug in Qt. See the bug report I submitted here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed in Qt 5.1.0 and onwards. See the following codereview url for details:

https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,57418

Comment: And it looks like the bug returned in later versions: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-29836

Comment: It is still broken in 5.15