# Pyside2 QQmlPropertyMap's slot not accessible from QML; Python version of old C++ bug?

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I've encountered what seems very much like a modern, Python version of a bug that was fixed years ago in (C++) Qt: [Can't call slot or Q_INVOKABLE from QML in subclass of QQmlPropertyMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016258/cant-call-slot-or-q-invokable-from-qml-in-subclass-of-qqmlpropertymap)

I tested the example in the question on my system (Qt 5.15.0, modifying syntax as needed) and verified that it is indeed fixed; the object's slot is correctly accessed, whether it inherits from QObject or QQmlPropertyMap.

However, still using Qt 5.15.0, working from PySide2 seems to replicate the same issue:

main.py:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Property, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, QQmlPropertyMap

class MyObj(QObject):
    @Property(str)
    def field(self):
        return 'Field from QObject'
    
    @Slot()
    def test_func(self):
        print('QObject signal worked')

class MyMap(QQmlPropertyMap):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.insert('field', 'Field from QQmlPropertyMap')
    
    @Slot()
    def test_func(self):
        print('QQmlPropertyMap signal worked')

app = QGuiApplication()
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

qobj = MyObj()
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('qobj', qobj)

qmap = MyMap()
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('qmap', qmap)

engine.load('main.qml')
app.exec_()
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Text {
        text: qobj.field + '\n' + qmap.field
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            qobj.test_func();
            qmap.test_func();
        }
    }
}
```

Both fields display properly in the generated window, but clicking on it produces this console output:

```
QObject slot worked
file:///Users/charles/Projects/qt/map-signal-test/main.qml:20: TypeError: Property 'test_func' of object QQmlPropertyMap(0x7fb954f5f460) is not a function
```

I don't know much about how PySide2 is implemented. Is this the same bug, unfixed or resurfacing? Or is it something else? In either event, is there a workaround?

EDIT:
In response to eyllanesc's answer below. While your posted code reproduces the error in C++, this somewhat different class definition (derived from the old question linked above) works correcty:

```
class MyMap: public QQmlPropertyMap {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyMap(QObject* parent = 0): QQmlPropertyMap(this, parent) {}
public slots:
    Q_INVOKABLE void test_func() {
        qDebug() << "QQmlPropertyMap signal worked";
    }
};
```

I don't know enough about C++ to understand the implication there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is a Qt bug, check the comments in [QTBUG-29836](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-29836). I have verified it with the following MRE with Qt 5.15:

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlPropertyMap>

class MyMap: public QQmlPropertyMap{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QQmlPropertyMap::QQmlPropertyMap;
    Q_INVOKABLE void test_func(){
        qDebug() << "QQmlPropertyMap signal worked";
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    MyMap qmap;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("qmap", &qmap);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            qmap.test_func()
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

It seems that the workaround of that bug is to use the [protected constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlpropertymap.html#QQmlPropertyMap-1) that uses the QMetaObject of the derived class, unlike the [default constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlpropertymap.html#QQmlPropertyMap) that only accesses the QMetaObject of QQmlProperty, therefore the elements like the Q_SLOTS, Q_INVOKABLES, etc of the new class are mapped. Unfortunately that constructor is not accessible from Python.

Comment: @CrazyChucky are you sure? I have executed it with Qt 5.15 in QtCreator, and in the console of "Application Output" I get: `qrc:/main.qml:12: TypeError: Property 'test_func' of object QQmlPropertyMap(0x7fffc6dc5a40) is not a function`

Comment: It appears what I got by copying and trimming from the old question is slightly different. It works, while yours doesn't. I don't know enough about C++ to understand the differences. Should I edit it into my question?

Comment: @CrazyChucky **Add** the code that works for you **at the end** of your post

Comment: Okay, posted. (Not sure if you get notified of that by default.)

Comment: P.S. I filed a bug report for PySide, in case it can be fixed to use the correct constructor: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1341