# Invoke slot of child of child of QQmlPropertyMap?

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qt-signals

Before marking this as a duplicate of "Can't call slot or Q_INVOKABLE from QML in subclass of QQmlPropertyMap," please read the final response (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18674363/447438).

I am working on a design where I have a class (call it `MyBaseClass`) that inherits from QQmlPropertyMap. It implements some additional behaviors for my system which are then used by other classes that inerit from `MyBaseClass` (e.g. `ChildClass`).

From QML, (QtQuick), I wish to invoke a slot (`mySlot()`) of `ChildClass`.  When I try, I get the following issues in the Application Output (mentioning `MyBaseClass`) even though I am only using `ChildClass`.

```
qrc:/main.qml:17: TypeError: Property 'mySlot' of object MyBaseClass(0x55f88ef86b50) is not a function
qrc:/main.qml:24: TypeError: Property 'mySlot' of object MyBaseClass(0x55f88ef86b50) is not a function
```

I also tried implementing sending signals from QML, but I get a similar issue trying to bind to the QML emitted signals.  (I am not adding that example.)

For those suggesting I just inherit QQmlPropertyMap into ChildClass (in addition to MyBaseClass to which it already has the proper inheritance and intialization via the protected method), the result is not pretty:

```
/home/jwerner/Projects/InheritanceTest-simple/ChildClass.h:8: warning: direct base 'QQmlPropertyMap' is inaccessible due to ambiguity:
    class ChildClass -> class MyBaseClass -> class QQmlPropertyMap
    class ChildClass -> class QQmlPropertyMap
```

My "gut" says that the problem is I am not doing things the "Qt Way," but I can't figure out what it is.

Here is the minimum example code of the problem to demonstrate the problem.  (I'm leaving out the .pro file since it is trivial to make.)

**MyBaseClass.h**

```
#include <QQmlPropertyMap>

class MyBaseClass : public QQmlPropertyMap
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyBaseClass(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QQmlPropertyMap(this, parent)
    {}

};
```

**ChildClass.h**

```
#include "MyBaseClass.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class ChildClass : public MyBaseClass
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ChildClass(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : MyBaseClass(parent) {}

public slots:
    void mySlot() {
        qDebug() << "This is mySlot";
    };
};
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15


Window {
    id: theMainWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property QtObject   cData: childData;

    onCDataChanged: {
        childData.mySlot();
    }

    Timer { // wait a bit before calling
        repeat: false
        interval: 2000
        running: true
        onTriggered: childData.mySlot();
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    auto childData = new ChildClass();

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperties({
        QQmlContext::PropertyPair{"childData",  QVariant::fromValue(childData)},
    });
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
        &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
            if (!obj && url == objUrl)
                QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The link you provides links to a bug report which links back to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlpropertymap.html#details), which includes this bit: "Note: When deriving a class from QQmlPropertyMap, use the protected two-argument constructor which ensures that the class is correctly registered with the Qt Meta-Object System."

Comment: JarMan,  The base class (MyBaseClass) is already doing that. Trying to add the inheritance from QQmlPropertyMap to ChildClass brings up an error. "/home/jwerner/Projects/InheritanceTest-simple/ChildClass.h:8: warning: direct base 'QQmlPropertyMap' is inaccessible due to ambiguity:
    class ChildClass -> class MyBaseClass -> class QQmlPropertyMap
    class ChildClass -> class QQmlPropertyMap"

Comment: @jwernerny You cannot multiply-derive from QObject, so of course re-inheriting from `QQmlPropertyMap` won't work and it wasn't implied I'm sure.

Comment: "I am working on a design where I have a class (call it MyBaseClass) that inherits from QQmlPropertyMap" - that's the root of the problem. The "Qt Way" requires a clear answer as to why that's necessary and what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps it's an unnecessary complication. `QQmlPropertyMap` is not necessary at all if the properties are not dynamically created, in such case Qt 6's bindable properties do it.

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a reusable way of passing data from a C++ interface layer to QML display layer. Each thing we interface to has it own data and may have things we need to trigger from the UI. We don't know all of the data for things yet (and it keeps changing), so having the ability to create dynamic data is a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the 2-argument `QQmlPropertyMap` constructor is a *template* constructor that needs the type of the [most] derived class (the documentation could be clearer on that, but that's the only way to make it work with automagic registration). The only type it ever sees is that of `MyBaseClass`.

You need to pass the type of the derived class to that constructor, e.g. by making a protected `MyBaseClass` constructor **templated** and giving it the same signature as that of `QQmlPropertyMap`, and then invoking that from `MyChildClass`. The alternative of making `MyBaseClass` a CRTP template class only works if that class doesn't add any properties nor signals nor slots.

Thus:

```
#include <QQmlPropertyMap>

class MyBaseClass : public QQmlPropertyMap
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    template <typename Derived>
    explicit MyBaseClass(Derived *derived, QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QQmlPropertyMap(derived, parent)
    {}
};
```

The constructor should be protected since `MyBaseClass` won't be usable by itself, I presume. You can always add a single-argument public constructor if you wish:

```
public:
    MyBaseClass(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QQmlPropertyMap(this, parent) {}
```

And then:

```
#include "MyBaseClass.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class ChildClass /* final, or see below */ : public MyBaseClass
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ChildClass(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : MyBaseClass(this, parent) {}   // notice the additional argument

protected:
    // if this class is not final, then add:
    template <typename Derived>
    ChildClass(Derived *derived, QObject *parent = nullptr)
         : MyBaseClass(derived, parent) {}

public slots:
    void mySlot() { qDebug() << "This is mySlot"; };
};
```

Note that **either** of the following must be present:

1. Declaration of `class ChildClass` as a final class, *or*
2. The templated protected 2-argument constructor.

It is a design mistake to have neither of the two, or both.

Comment: I have been thinking about going with templates. I'll give it some try and run it against my unit tests for the real code.  I think tend to think inheritance first, then templates.

Comment: I've tested in our real application, and it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it worked, but I can't say I recommend this as a solution. It kind of negates the purpose of having a base class if it has to know about its derived types.

```
// Forward-declare the derived type so it can be passed to the constructor
class ChildClass;

class MyBaseClass : public QQmlPropertyMap
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyBaseClass(ChildClass *derivedObj, QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QQmlPropertyMap(derivedObj, parent)
    {}

};
```

Comment: The whole point is to make it a *template* constructor. No need to forward declare anything, and no need to know the child class's type ahead of time. `QQmlPropertyMap` already does that, you can basically copy-paste the idea (well, you have to, there's only one way to do it).

Comment: Yes, you’re right of course. I posted this because it worked, but knew it was bad code. Glad there’s a better way.